# User Defined Variable In VBScript

Tags: vbscript, putty

I am trying to write a VBScript to log in to PUTTY and execute bunch of commands. I am trying to take the UserID and Password for login from the Input box and then pass it as a variable for login.

But I am not able to pass `UserName` and `Passwrd` properly. Please suggest.

```
Dim UserName
Dim Passwrd


UserName = InputBox("Please Enter Your UserID:")
Passwrd  = InputBox("Please Enter Your Password:")


Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
pcmd = "putty.exe -ssh UserName@10.177.104.109 -pw Passwrd"
Set exec = shell.Exec(pcmd)
Set pout = exec.StdOut
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use string concatenation (`&`) to combine your variable values with your string literal:

```
pcmd = "putty.exe -ssh " & UserName & "@10.177.104.109 -pw " & Passwrd
```